# How can I paste a value into the page using a button?

Tags: javascript, paste

Google sheet has their own menu bar, and when I click EDIT and PASTE, I can paste text. How can I achieve this?

I added clipboard API on google chrome, but safari and Firefox do not work.
What I noticed is when I click PASTE on safari, it will show right click menu, and let me paste text.

Is there any way to pop up menu with paste button and paste text?

[image]